# Django queryset excluding many to many objects

Tags: django, django-queryset, models

Let's assume we have a model:

```
 class a(models.Model):
     users = models.ManyToManyField(User) # django.contrib.auth.models.User
```

and these variables:

```
user = request.user
queryset = a.objects.all()
```

Then I want to exclude these records from a model that contains the user in users. How can I do that?

```
queryset.exclude(...)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
queryset.exclude(users=user)
```